# Facebook Login - What data does Facebook collect from my app/my users on my app?

Tags: facebook-login

I am curious about Facebook Login, does Facebook collect user data from my app/my users after they login using Facebook Login? I know I can apply to receive user data from Facebook (ie: user demographic data, or user friends, etc), but does Facebook collect any data from my app/site in return? I feel like I have read the facebook login dev support pages a few times and can't seem to find an answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: facebook already got all the data. it´s where you get your data from, after login...

Comment: Yeah but do they  (Facebook) get data from my user relative to my app? How they use it, what they do there, etc? I assume they are able to know when users logged in, since they are authenticating via Facebook, but more than that what do they get from my user?

Comment: login works through facebook, so obviously they know. you can even see the insights for that in the app settings. and of course whenever you do an api call to their servers, they know. not sure what else you want to know, to be honest...